# PHP ffmpeg not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, ffmpeg, exec, video-conversion

so I already browse all the forum but I still get error "sh: 1: /usr/bin/ffmpeg: not found".
If I run ffmpeg from terminal it works just fine and can do convert video without problem, but if I use PHP exec or shell_exec, the return always ffmpeg not found.

this is my code :

```php
$cmd = "/usr/bin/ffmpeg";

$run = exec($cmd." -i 'linkvideo.m3u8' -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -vcodec copy -c copy -crf 50 /test_stream/newfile.mp4 2>&1");

var_dump($run);
```

if I run which ffmpeg or whereis ffmpeg from terminal it will return /usr/bin/ffmpeg, but if I exec('which ffmpeg') from my code it will return ffmpeg not found. I already chown and chmod the ffmpeg to grant rwx, i tried move ffmpeg to /usr/local/bin still same result. If i run whoami from terminal it will show root but if from my code using exec('whoami') it will show www-data so maybe I miss something about the user but I also already tried to chown ffmpeg from root to www-data still the result is ffmpeg not found, maybe anyone can help, I'm using codeigniter and already install ffmpeg in server using sudo apt-get ffmpeg, thanks before!

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if your webserver user is able to run ffmpeg?

Comment: sorry I don't know how to check that. What I know is I can run ffmpeg from command line in server as root, but I don't know why I can't run it using PHP exec

Answer (score 1):

Download FFmpeg and ffprobe after than put a folder in third_part folder in application.

```
    try {
        $FFMpeg = FFMpeg\FFProbe::create([
            'ffmpeg.binaries'  => APPPATH . '/third_party/ffmpeg',
            'ffprobe.binaries'  => APPPATH . '/third_party/ffprobe',
        ]);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        try {
            $FFMpeg = FFMpeg\FFProbe::create([
                'ffmpeg.binaries' => '/usr/bin/ffmpeg',
                'ffprobe.binaries' => '/usr/bin/ffprobe'
            ]);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new Exception("However Unable to load FFProbe driver for FFmpeg");
        };
    };
```

Also; change the second try if you use a different OS than Ubuntu.

For Mac OS :

```
'ffmpeg.binaries'  => '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg',
'ffprobe.binaries' => '/usr/local/bin/ffprobe'
```

For Windows :

```
'ffmpeg.binaries'  => 'C:/FFmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe',
'ffprobe.binaries' => 'C:/FFmpeg/bin/ffprobe.exe'
```

For Ubuntu :

```
'ffmpeg.binaries' => '/usr/bin/ffmpeg',   
'ffprobe.binaries' => '/usr/bin/ffprobe'
```

Comment: yes it works fine on local server but the class FFMpeg is not found when I uploaded to the server

Comment: Use the above code, the second try is for Ubuntu.